# Jenkins & .NET Build server

Tags: jenkins, build, windows-server-2012-r2

I would like to raise from scratch a build server for .NET applications using Jenkins, please note that i'm new to Jenkins CI.

Several Questions:

1) How should I decide on the build server specs? except for the OS which would be windows server 2012, how should I decide on the RAM and the CPU and HD space?

2) Should the Jenkins sit in the build machine or not, what is the recommended approach? I understood that the build server should be isolated from the Jenkins master

3) How do I decide on the Master/Slave approach, when should I use only Master and when should I use master and slave or slaves?

4) How would you recommend me to run the build and deployment tasks in the Jenkins CI, using NAnt/Python or any other scripting language ?

10x, and sorry for the igonrance :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Responding to each in turn:

1. You can run Jenkins as a windows service (instructions [here](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Installing+Jenkins+as+a+Windows+service)) and the machine can be a VM, so it doesn't have to be huge.
   a) RAM and CPU: I'll put these together and will depend on how many jobs you plan to have running at the same time.  The default number of build executors is 3 but can be increased as a global config change.
   b) HDD: This depends on how many jobs you plan to have.  Jenkins will checkout the source code (as well as the compiled output) to its home directory on a per job basis.  This can get big.  I would also recommend using the ThinBackup [plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/thinBackup) to backup the Jenkins configuration.
2. Jenkins is the build machine.  A vanilla installation of Jenkins is the master.  In my experience you will not need a separate slave machine unless you're needing to do native builds on other platforms or have LOTS and LOTS of jobs.  I've seen single masters running happily with hundreds of jobs.
3. Further to 2. above, suggest you start with a master and set up a slave later if you really need one.
4. As you have stated you are building .NET applications, you can simply install the MSBuild [plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/MSBuild+Plugin) which should serve you well.  Builds for .NET applications in Jenkins are Freestyle builds so you will be using Windows Batch build steps often as well. This also is a great [blog](http://jenkinsheaven.blogspot.com) on Jenkins in a .NET environment.